# VS Code Customize Tab Colors

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I change VS Code tab colors? Is there an attribute in *settings.json* (i.e. a corollary to `"tab.activeBorder": "#18aa83"`) for background color?

[image: VS Code tabs]

Comment: It would be great to have an extension for this.

Comment: More information on styling tabs, can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-groups-tabs

Comment: I wrote an extension which colors the active tab based on some file regex, making it super comfortable when working on monorepos or client/server shared repos. Check it out - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=orepor.color-tabs-vscode-ext

Comment: @carloswm85 you can try https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mondersky.tabscolor

Comment: @mondersky awesome. It looks pretty good. It has some pretty nice features. Thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 62):

VS Code documents color customizations for tabs in the [theme color api](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-groups-tabs).

To edit the tab colors you can use the following identifiers:

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "tab.activeBackground": "#ff0000",
        "tab.inactiveBackground": "#ff0000"
    }
}
```

You add that to your `settings.json` file

[image: tab picture]

To change the tabs header you can use the following:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground": "#ff0000",
}
```

[image: header group picture]

---

You can type `tab.` and it will suggest similar properties you can change

Comment: Greaty! Tranks for answer.

Comment: how do I get to settings.json ?

Answer (score 5):

In settings.json , add below details. It will be helpful as some text colors are dim. This setting works well.

Also if you want to set colors based on themes this will be helpful.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Visual Studio Dark]": {
        "tab.activeBorderTop": "#6a6ce4",
        "tab.activeBackground": "#182952",
        "tab.activeBorder": "#6a6ce4"
    },
    "[Default Dark+]": {
        "tab.activeBorderTop": "#6a6ce4",
        "tab.activeBackground": "#180753",
        "tab.activeBorder": "#6a6ce4"
    },
    "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#1073cf2d",
    "editor.lineHighlightBorder": "#9fced11f"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only target the active tab with the theme color API though, the only workaround I found to this is to patch vs code and inject arbitrary javascript code that will manipulate the tabs html, [tabsColor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mondersky.tabscolor) does this

[image]