# Can barely see vscode editor tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: vscode tabs]

I can barely identify the vscode tab that is open, I am trying to change the color of the "opened". I don't know what name it identify as.

For example I would like to set the opened tab title background as gold or something instead of black

[Edit]
I would also appreciate if I could change to text color on the tab title to pure white

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63146997/vscode-customize-tab-colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63146997/vscode-customize-tab-colors)

Comment: What about the text in the tab, do you know the key, please 